# Unexpected outcome, not replacing, in R out of a gsub function

Tags: r, regex, gsub

As the output of a certain operation, I have the following dataframe whith 729 observations.

```
> head(con)
              Connections
1  r_con[C3-C3,Intercept]
2  r_con[C3-C4,Intercept]
3 r_con[C3-CP1,Intercept]
4 r_con[C3-CP2,Intercept]
5 r_con[C3-CP5,Intercept]
6 r_con[C3-CP6,Intercept]
```

As can be seen, the pattern to be removed is everything but the pair of Electrode information, for instance, in the first observation this would be `C3-C3`. Now, this is my take on the issue, which I'd expect to have the dataframe with everything removed. If I'm not wrong (which probably am) the regex syntax is ok and from my understanding I believe `fixed=TRUE` is also necessary. However, I do not understand the R output. When I would expect the pattern to be changed by nothing `""`it returns this output, which doesn't make sense to me.

```
> gsub("r_con\\[\\,Intercept\\]\\","",con,fixed=TRUE)

[1] "3:731"
```

I believe this will probably be a silly question for an expert programmer, which I am far from being, and any insight would be much appreciated.

[UPDATE WITH SOLUTION]

Thanks to Tim and Ben I realised I was using a wrong regex syntax and a wrong source, this made it to me:

```
con2 <- sub("^r_con\\[([^,]+),Intercept\\]", "\\1", con$Connections)
```

Comment: Can you please post the output of  `class(con$Connections[1])`?

Comment: Sure! It is a ```[1] "factor"```.

Comment: I updated the post because I was using ```gsub``` and I unwillingly typed ```sub```, in case it is significant. Although I tried with both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `sub` function doesn't work this way.  One viable approach would be to capture the quantity you want, then use this capture group as the replacement:

```r
x <- "r_con[C3-C3,Intercept]"
term <- sub("^r_con\\[([^,]+),Intercept\\]", "\\1", x)
term

[1] "C3-C3"
```

Comment: Sorry Tim, I am not sure if I follow, so the thing is I cannot change all the occurrences at once?

Comment: After using your regex sintax in my example though, it looks like I had it wrong. Now it works fine. Thanks very much!!

Comment: @UnaiVicente Use the following to change the entire column: `con$Connections <- sub("^r_con\\[([^,]+),Intercept\\]", "\\1", con$Connections)`

Answer (score 3):

I think your problem is that you're accessing "con" in your `sub` call. Also, as the user above me pointed out, you probably don't want to use `sub`.

I'm assuming, that your data is consistent, i.e., the strings in `con$Connections` follow more or less the same pattern. Then, this works:

I have set up this example:

```
con <- data.frame(Connections = c("r_con[C3-C3,Intercept]", "r_con[C3-CP1,Intercept]"))
library(stringr)
f <- function(x){
  part <- str_split(x, ",")[[1]][1]
  str_sub(part, 7, -1)
}

f(con$Connections[1])
sapply(con$Connections, f)
```

Comment: This is the output I get:```> con2 <- sub("r_con\\[\\,Intercept\\]\\","",con$Connections,fixed=TRUE)``` ```> head(con2)
[1] "r_con[C3-C3,Intercept]"  "r_con[C3-C4,Intercept]"  "r_con[C3-CP1,Intercept]" "r_con[C3-CP2,Intercept]"
[5] "r_con[C3-CP5,Intercept]" "r_con[C3-CP6,Intercept]"``` so basically nothing changed.

Comment: try the new approach, I just made an edit

Comment: I took the con$Connection of yours and the syntax from @Tim and now it works fine. I'll update the post with the solution in case someone finds it useful. Thanks very much!!